# How do I get commits from a merged and reverted PR into a new one?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

To make a long story short, I am in the following situation:

A feature branch was created, worked on for a while collecting some 30 commits, and merged into `master`. The merge was then reverted through GitHub's web interface (by creating a new PR that reverted the effects of the old one).

Now, I have fixed the problems that caused us to revert the merge, and I'd like to create a new PR with both all of the 30 or so commits from the original PR and a couple of more for my fix.

I've based my feature-fix branch on the (unmerged) head of the feature branch, committed a couple of times more and then pushed to create a PR - but for some reason, the PR only picks up the new commits, not the old ones.

How do I include the old commits in my new PR?

I have push access to the repo (we're using the [shared repo model](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/#shared-repository-model)) so almost any operations that don't require a force-push to `master` are OK.

Simplified git history:

```
* [feature-fix]  <-- This is the branch I want to pull from now
| * [master]
| * [merge revert PR]
* |\
| | * [revert PR]
* |/              <-- This is the first commit included in the new PR by github
| * [merge PR]
|/|
* | [feature]  <-- This is where the original PR came from
| |
* |   <-- I want these commits, originally included in the old PR, to be included
* |       in my new PR too.
| |
* | <-- Started work on feature here. This is the first commit I want to include.
 \|
  * <-- Common ancestor between `feature-fix` and `master`, as far as I can see
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly you need to do the following.

```
git checkout master
git revert SHA_OF_MERGE_REVERT_PR
git merge feature-fix
```

The key step is reverting the commit that reverted your merge.  That SHA removed all your changes, but preserved all your merge history which is why you are only seeing the new commits.

You can read more about it from Linus himself [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

Comment: That seems reasonable. I'll have to try it when I get back to work tomorrow.